# Shutdown icon missing after logout

Tags: unity, icons, shutdown, logout

After a recent upgrade, the shutdown (or Hibernate) icon remains missing after logout.

The icon is visible after boot, after logging in, but as soon as I logout, the only icon that is visible at top right is that one with human interface functionalities or some such.

This happens in at least three computers I use. All are running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: That update sounds like a Windows update :)

Comment: @AndroidDev Somehow fail to understand what you wanted to mean by this comment.

Comment: Windows update are notorious for breaking things. So I was saying that the update you applied sounds like a Windows update. It was a joke

Comment: @AndroidDev Thanks. Somehow being forced to move to the console terminal and shutdown using command line every time I logout made me a bit too serious and I missed the joke.

Comment: Could you maybe include some screenshots? (Taken with a camera if need be)

Comment: Similarly for me, every icon except the Universal Access is missing anymore after logging out. I cannot shutdown by Ubuntu 16.04 machine anymore if I log out first.